# How to build exposed API in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to build exposed API that is called by another web service in order to insert data.

```
Here is DB structure.
Table name: bad_domain
attributes are :
domain(string)
modified_by(string)
cereated_by(string)
risk(Boolean)
```

Here is my code in defauly.py

```
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True

@auth.requires_login()
@request.restful()
def api():
    def POST(table_name,**vars):
    return db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)
return locals()
```

Here is my curl

```
curl --user test@gmail.com:1234 http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/api/bad_domain.json {"content": [{"domain": “www.google.com”,”modified_by”:”test”, "created_by": "test", "risk": True}]}
```

curl dose not work.

Any idea how to fix curl commend.

I am pretty new to web2py

Thank you.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? (And please show us actual error messages or output instead of just describing it vaguely.)

Comment: data dose not go to DB

Comment: Does `curl` actually even run and connect to the server? (There's no way it possibly could with the command line you gave us.) If so, does the server log anything? Does it return something to your client? Also, if this based on some example or skeleton, so we can just drop in your extra code and run it? If not, can you give us a complete minimal example?

Answer (score 2):

If this is your actual `curl` command:

```
curl --user test@gmail.com:1234 http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/api/bad_domain.json {"content": [{"domain": “www.google.com”,”modified_by”:”test”, "created_by": "test", "risk": True}]}
```

Then you've got at least five problems:

1. Most shells will try to interpret that JSON in some way. It's got embedded spaces, and braces and brackets, and so on. Put it in quotes.
2. Even if you quote it so it gets through the shell unscathed, you forgot the `--data` flag, so `curl` will treat it as another URL, instead of as data to send.
3. You're not doing anything to tell `curl` to set the `Content-Type` properly.
4. Even if you get past that, all those smart-quote characters like `“` are not quotes as far as JSON is concerned, so you'll be sending garbage that the server will reject.
5. `True` is not a valid JSON value; you probably wanted `true`.

So, let's start with this:

```
curl --user test@gmail.com:1234 http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/default/api/bad_domain.json --data '{"content": [{"domain": "www.google.com","modified_by":"test", "created_by": "test", "risk": true}]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

At least that will send something reasonable to the server, with a body that can be parsed by `json.loads`. Whether it's what you actually wanted to send, or whether your code can handle it, I don't know, but it should at least get you started.